# how to convert this JavaScript object that contains an array to JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

This JavaScript object contains an array that I need to convert to JSON (but I cannot change the object because this is the response from some API):

https://api.github.com/orgs/moment/members

short example (but please use the real one from the link):

```
{
    [
        { login: 'abc', id: 1234567890},
        { login: 'xyz', id: 0987654321}
    ]
}
```

the problem is that when I try to use

```
JSON.stringify(response)
```

I get the error: Converting circular structure to JSON

I have also tried

```
JSON.stringify({'data': response});
```

Comment: Why is it identifying as circular?  I do not see why, but a suggestion might be to use something like this.  https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json

Comment: JSON dictionary : `{"key":<value>}`. JSON list : `[<value>]`. Syntax error : `{<value>}`. When you pick an example, stick to it.

Comment: `use the real one from the link` - works fine, because it is a JSON response - perhaps you want to `JSON.parse` JSON to an object?

Comment: unless you've added something to the response in your link after you parsed it to an object, there's no problem stringifying it - the link is JSON, so parsing then stringifying will work 100%

Comment: You are omitting some details. Be more specific please.

Comment: Please note that the response is being generated by github.com not me!

Comment: JSON.stringify on the response worked fine here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response has DATA that is the array so instead of JSON.parse or JSON.stringify I decided to create a new object and filter out what I do not need.

```
    const axios = require("axios");
    const url = "https://api.github.com/orgs/moment/members";
    axios.get(url).then(members => {
        let data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            let member = {};
            member['login'] = response.data[i].login;
            member['avatar_url'] = response.data[i].avatar_url;
            member['html_url'] = response.data[i].html_url;
            data.push(member);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You Object have not key try this

```
{
 "myNewKey" : [
                 { login: 'abc', id: 1234567890},
                 { login: 'xyz', id: 0987654321}
              ]
}
```

or you can try this

```
[
   { login: 'abc', id: 1234567890},
   { login: 'xyz', id: 0987654321}
]
```